# Rounding Corners: How to calculate Fillet radius?

Tags: ios, math, core-graphics, geometry

How do I find the maximum rounding I can apply to either corner for any amount of rounding on the other corner?

Answers to questions from the comments:

1) **The inner and outer large arcs (those that are 90 degrees wide here) always have the same center**

**2) When asking for the maximum rounding that you can do, what are the constraints on the other, smaller circle? Does it need to be at least some radius? Otherwise you are doing to end up with just one rounding.**

One of the two rounding circle's radius is given. There are no other constraints other than the maximum of the other circle which I just can't find. 
If the "fixed" corner that I refer to has zero rounding then I'm searching for the maximum rouding that can be applied with only the other corner.

**3) What constitutes as the maximum rounding? Are you trying to choose between the two examples above? Or is finding either of those cases considered a solution?**

Either of the shown cases is a perfect solution. E.g. in the first image the the radius of the smaller circle might be given. Then I'm looking for the maximum radius of the larger one.
These images are just examples for perfect solutions.

**4) is there any constraints on the two arcs? What happens if the arcs can't fit a full circle? Would the answer be the largest that fits?**

How exactly do you mean that the arcs can't fit a full circle?

The all circles are perfect circles, but I can't figure out the max size of the rounding possible, or how to calculate it's position.  Here's some images that describe the problem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: While your images are nice and makes it clear what you are asking for, there are a couple of details that are missing that have a big impact on the scope of the question: **1)** is the inner and outer arcs always concentric (have the same center)? **2)** When asking for the *maximum* rounding that you can do, what are the constraints on the other, smaller circle? Does it need to be at least some radius? Otherwise you are doing to end up with just one rounding. **3)** What constitutes as the *maximum* rounding? Are you trying to choose between the two examples above? Or is finding either ...

Comment: ... Or is finding either of those cases considered a solution? **4)** is there any constraints on the two arcs? What happens if the arcs can't fit a full circle? Would the answer be the largest that fits?

Comment: Hey David, I'm stunne you found my question! I know a lot of your answer and learned a lot from them! So I'm glad to asnwer you questions (I'm going to edit the description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the origin of the coordinate system is at the center point of the inner and outer large arcs...

For the first case where the large circle is tangent to the outer edge, the center point of the large circle is

```
x = R cos(t) / (1 + cos(t))
y = R sin(t) / (1 + cos(t))
```

where R is the radius of the outer arc segment, and `t` is the angle between the x-axis and the ray from the origin through the center of the large circle.

For the second case where the large circle is tangent to the inner edge, the center point of the large circle is

```
x = R cos(t) / (1 - cos(t))
y = R sin(t) / (1 - cos(t))
```

where R is the radius of the inner arc segment, and `t` is the angle...

In both cases, the radius of the circle is equal to its x coordinate. The range of `t` is between some minimum angle and PI/2. At PI/2, the circle is vanishingly small.  At the minimum angle, the y value is equal to the opposite radius.  In other words, for the first case where the large circle is tangent to the outer edge, the minimum angle is such that y is equal to the inner radius.  Whereas if the circle is tangent to the inner edge, the minimum angle is such that y is equal to the outer radius.  It can be proven mathematically that the minimum angle is the same for both cases (tangent to inner and tangent to outer both have the same minimum angle for a given inner and outer radius). However, computing the minimum angle is a bit of a challenge.  The only way I know how to do it is by playing the high/low game, e.g.

```
- (CGFloat)computeAngleForOuterTangentGivenY:(CGFloat)Y
{
    CGFloat y;
    double high = M_PI_2;
    double low  = 0;
    double mid  = M_PI_4;

    while ( high - low > 1e-9 )
    {
        y = (self.outerRadius * sin( mid )) / (1.0 + cos( mid ));
        if ( y > Y )
            high = mid;
        else
            low = mid;
        mid = (low + high) / 2.0;
    }

    return( mid );
}

- (CGFloat)computeAngleForInnerTangentGivenY:(CGFloat)Y
{
    CGFloat y;
    double high = M_PI_2;
    double low  = 0;
    double mid  = M_PI_4;

    while ( high - low > 1e-9 )
    {
        y = (self.innerRadius * sin( mid )) / (1.0 - cos( mid ));
        if ( y > Y )
            low = mid;
        else
            high = mid;
        mid = (low + high) / 2.0;
    }

    return( mid );
}
```

It takes about 30 passes for the loop to converge to an answer.

To find the coordinates of the small circle, note that the small circle has the same y value as the large circle, and is tangent to the opposite edge of the arc segment. Therefore, compute the angle `t` for the small circle based on its y value using the appropriate high/low algorithm, and then compute the x value using the formulas above.

QED

Comment: Thanks!, I was actually hoping for a solution without a loop but maybe that's not too easy. With the help of this I am able to calculate the maximum radius and also apply it to other start and end angles of the arc segment (other than a 90 degree wide arc)

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't posed correctly without showing both ends of the line segment.  Suppose for a moment that each line segment is a data structure that maintains not only the end points, but also cap radius in each point, and also knows the angle going out to the next endpoint that this line will attach to.  Each cap radius will subtract from the length of the line segment that has to be stroked as a rectangle.  Assume you have a line of interest between points B and C, where B joins to another (longer) segment A, and C joins to another (longer) segment D.  If line BC is length 10, with cap radius B and cap radius C both set to 4, then you will only render rectangle of length 2 for the straight part of the line segment, while length 4 is used to draw the arc to A, and another length 4 is used to draw the arc to D.

Furthermore, the maximum cap radius for C is constrained not only by BC and B's cap radius, but also by CD and D's cap radius.

Comment: And as for calculating positions... The center point of the arc for drawing either the center of the lie or the inner/outer parts will lie on a bisector of the angle between the intersecting lines, and will be equidistant from the endpoints on the lines that were drawn as rectangles.  (ie: convert a list of points into a list of lines.  convert list of lines into alternating list of caps and segments).